# Can I use Ascorbic acid powder as a preservative to extend the shelf life in pickled brine recipe?

Tags: acid-base

Can I use Ascorbic acid powder as a preservative to extend the shelf life  in pickled brine recipe made with vinegar?

Answer (score 2):

Ascorbic acid may serve as antioxidant preservative, but not as antimicrobial preservative.

Unless it is present in comparable amount as added acetic acid and  lactic acid formed by fermentation, but it would keep it redundant.